# Selenium getting banned from cloudflare

Tags: python, selenium, cloudflare

I am using selenium python but when I load my target page it gets banned.
I find if I run this code while trying load page then everything getting fine.

```
driver.service.stop()
```

Cloudflare is accept my connection and my target page is loaded success.
But still don't know how to deal with Cloudflare because when I resume selenium in current browser then Cloudflare continue ban me. What should I do? I use proxy to change my ip and anti-detected browser named Gologin already.
[my target page keeps loading to infinity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O5iT.png)

Comment: Cloudflare blocks selenium. As far as I know, there is no way around it.

Comment: my script is work well for half year ago but last week the cloudflare banned me. Is there any ideals?

Answer (score 2):

When I run into this problem I usually use a library called "cloudscraper"
Read more about it here: https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper

Comment: seem like "cloudscraper" not supported for selenium webdriver. Do you use selenium webdriver with cloudscraper

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).